# shadowbox 3.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I am trying to use shadowbox 3.0.3 in google chrome

I am getting:

in chrome

> shadowbox.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

in firefox

> F is undefined
>    g.find=(function(){var aD=/((?:((?:(...()}};g.skin=k;T.Shadowbox=g})(window);
>   shadowbox.js (line 17)

seems to work fine in IE

My code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="shadowbox.js"></script>
    <link href="shadowbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            Shadowbox.init({skipSetup: true});

            // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
            Shadowbox.open({
                content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome to my website!</div>',
                player:     "html",
                title:      "Welcome",
                height:     350,
                width:      350
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

what would be causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use window.load method as suggested in the [docs](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
    skipSetup: true
});

$(window).load(function() {

    // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome to my website!</div>',
        player:     "html",
        title:      "Welcome",
        height:     350,
        width:      350
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but maybe Shadowbox.init() should go outside the $(function() ...), so that it is called before the window loads.  Thats what the example on their site suggests: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html